# What does いやよね mean in japanese?

Tags: meaning, words, word-usage, japanese-to-english

Is there a word such as いやよね ? I heard The Anime Man mention it in this video(https://youtu.be/k8UmX17DXWg) at around 14:34. However I couldn't find this word in any dictionary.

Comment: Are you trying to look it up as all one thing? Generally particles like よ or ね will be separate entries. You can probably find them together as よね as well, but they don't gain any special meaning that you can't determine from looking them up individually.

Comment: He used it as a single word. He said いやよね教団(iyayone kyoudan) most probably.

Comment: I don't think there's anything misleading about it, it's part of a proper noun (or at least is meant to be one, I didn't watch any more of the video) so it's not going to be bound to grammar rules of sentences or anything. Whether you call いやよね 1, 2 or 3 words based on how it was used there isn't really that meaningful of a distinction in the context of a proper noun. It only matters when trying to look up the parts.

Answer (score 3):

いや means "unpleasant"

よ in this context means "it is"

ね is used at the end of a sentence to solicit the listener's agreement with the speaker.

Put together the whole is "it's unpleasant, isn't it?"